# I cannot get the spectrum color picker to work. What am I missing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, colors, picker

Re: http://jsfiddle.net/bgrins/ctkY3/

I'm at a loss. I'm unable to get this color picker working (or any color picker).

Below is the total HTML content of the test page.

I have jquery linked.

As far as I can tell, the paths are correct on the links (.js and .css).

I also tried wrapping the inline initializations in a "$(document).ready(function()" but that did not help. All I get are regular text boxes.  It does not work for me on multiple browsers, and multiple devices.

Can anyone see something I missed?

It will probably be something simple and I'll be embarrassed, but I am desperate to get a good color picker working. This is about the 3rd one I've tried.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Spectrum Color Picker - Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="include/spectrum/spectrum.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="include/spectrum/spectrum.css" />

<script>
$(".basic").spectrum({
    color: "#f00",
    change: function(color) {
            $("#basic-log").text("change called: " + color.toHexString());
    }
});
</script>

</head>

<body>
<h2>Basic Usage</h2>
<input type='text' class="basic"/>
<em id='basic-log'></em>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note: the `<input>` and `<link>` tags do not use and do not need a closing slash and never have in HTML.

Comment: I would recommend you change `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js` to `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js` The browser is no doubt blocking `jQuery` from loading because you have mixed content "**HTTP**" on "**HTTPS**"

Comment: @Rob: Thanks. I have edited the test page to remove those, but the script still is not working.

Comment: @NewToJS: I am hosting the .js and .css files. I will indeed try changing the link to jquery to SSL to see if that helps! Thank you!

Comment: @NewToJS: Huzzah! That was it! Changing the jquery link to SSL did the trick!!!! Thank you! How can I mark your answer as the answer? Your answer shows up as a comment?

Comment: I am currently out at the moment but when I get home I will be sure to write up a detailed answer for you :)

Comment: If your update is the answer to the question then post it as an answer and mark it as such. If someone else answered your question, mark it as such. Do not put answers within the question! And do not post them as "Thanks". [ask]

Comment: @Rob: thanks. Will try to do better. I'm pretty new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/spectrum.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/spectrum.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>Basic Usage</h2>
    <input type='text' class="basic" />
    <em id='basic-log'></em>
    <script>
        $(".basic").spectrum({
            color: "#f00",
            change: function (color) {
                $("#basic-log").text("change called: " + color.toHexString());
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

This is definitely working, the only thing I can think of is that the `css` and `js` are not loaded correctly.

Comment: You could also place the source code in a  `jQuery` DOM ready function. For example `$(function(){/*---- Your Spectrum Code Here ----*/});`

Comment: @Andy-Song: Thanks. I tried that. Still nothing. :-/

Comment: @NewToJS: As I already mentioned in my original post, I already tried that. ->  "I also tried wrapping the inline initializations in a "$(document).ready(function()" but that did not help. "

Comment: @DougJoseph I think I have found your issue, please read my comment under your question. Thank you

Comment: @NewToJS: You did indeed! How can I mark your answer as the correct one? Do you need to post it as an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: @DougJoseph, my updated also pointing that is the `css` and `js` reference issue.

Comment: @AndySong: Thank you!

Comment: @DougJoseph, not going to consider to upvote my answer?

Comment: @AndySong: If I can upvote two answers, I want to upvote both NewToJS's answer and yours. If I can upvote only one, I would want to upvote his as he caught that first. Can I upvote two?

Comment: @DougJoseph, you can upvote as many asnwers as you want, but only once for each answer.

Comment: @DougJoseph, you can try it out if you want, just upvote my answer, and later if you find you can not upvote another one, you can always downvote my one.

Comment: @AndySong: I wanted to confirm I did upvote, however, apparently I'm so new my upvotes don't show. :-/

Answer (score 0):

**The answer was twofold.

1. The need to make sure "DOM READY" (document fully loaded) was part of it. This was accomplished in my case by placing the inline initialization script at the bottom, just above the closing body tag. It can also  be accomplished by wrapping the inline initializations in a "$(document).ready(function()"...
2. Also, the fact that I was serving an SSL page while trying to link a non-SSL version of JQuery was the other part it. By linking JQuery with "httpS://" (<- note the S) it took care of the second part of it! Live and learn!

Again, THANKS to @NewToJS AND @AndySong, who both got me the answers needed.**